# JIRA becomes inaccessible after adding "address=127.0.0.1" in Tomcat connector

Tags: nginx, tomcat, reverse-proxy

I have JIRA and Nginx running on the same server with Nginx installed to serve as a reverse proxy. From what I learnt from various sources, in the server.xml file, I must add an address="127.0.0.1" attribute so that Tomcat does not listen to outside IPs. But once I add that to my 8080 and 8443 connectors, things stop working i.e., the JIRA site becomes inaccessible. Browser displays Connection refused / connection timed out errors.

Here is server.xml file configuration for Tomcat.

```
<Connector port="8080" 
address="127.0.0.1" 
maxThreads="150" 
minSpareThreads="25" 
connectionTimeout="20000" 
enableLookups="false" 
maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" 
protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
useBodyEncodingForURI="true" 
acceptCount="100" 
redirectPort="8443" 
disableUploadTimeout="true" 
proxyName=<FQDN> 
proxyPort="80"/>

<Connector port="8443" 
address="127.0.0.1" 
SSLEnabled="true" 
acceptCount="100" 
clientAuth="false" 
connectionTimeout="20000" 
disableUploadTimeout="true" 
enableLookups="false" 
keyAlias=<value> 
keystoreFile=<jks file> 
keystorePass=<password> 
keystoreType="JKS" 
maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" 
maxSpareThreads="75" 
maxThreads="150" 
minSpareThreads="25"  
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" 
scheme="https" 
secure="true" 
sslProtocol="TLS" 
useBodyEncodingForURI="true"/>
```

and the Nginx server configuration in sites-enabled linked to sites-available folder -

```
    server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    server_name <FQDN>;
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1; #I have tried FQDN, real IP, :8080 suffix etc. but the response didn't change
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
}
```

What is wrong in my approach? It's largely derived from https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/integrating-jira-with-nginx-426115340.html except for adding the address attribute. The HTTPS connector block was derived (I guess it was auto-generated when I configured it) from Atlassian's standard SSL enabling instructions.

**Update 21 April**:
Here is my nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**Update 22 April**
I tried running curl -v FQDN and got this message in the error log. Terminal showed me 502 Bad gateway -

```
connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: <IP Address>, server: <FQDN>, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://<IP>:8080/", host: <FQDN>
```

Comment: Pls show full nginx conf

Comment: It appears that you are missing the `ProxyPass` lines. Is there more to your nginx configuration that you haven't shown?

Comment: @user1700494 added those details

Comment: @prateek61, I had it earlier but it didn't seem to help. So was trying out various options.

Comment: Try adding that block back in, but update `proxy_pass http://jira-hostname:8080/jira;` to be `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/jira;`.

Comment: In my case the JIRA URL is http://pcname.domain.com. I had tried http://pcname.domain.com and http://pcname.domain.com:8080. Not just that I had attempted to use localhost, 127.0.0.1 and the server's IP too.

Comment: what error have you got when used `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/jira`

Comment: Browser reports site refused to connect. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Try changing it to be just `proxy_pass HTTP://127.0.0.1:8080/`. Also, can you post the output of `iptables -S`?

Comment: I still get the 'Connection Refused' error. The output of iptables -s is -P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your proxy from Nginx is going to "127.0.0.1" instead of your server's / site's hostname or IP.

If this is done, you could have an issue with the Tomcat connector being on IPV4 (forced by 127.0.0.1) while Nginx is trying to get to it on the IPv6 stack.

Comment: can you provide me some tips about how that can be done? I'm a bit new to all these.

Comment: Share with us the contents of the referenced "include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;"  We need to see how you've configured your proxy.

Comment: I just updated my "Nginx server configuration in sites-enabled linked to sites-available folder" with the latest one I am using. That's the only file present in sites-available sym linked to sites-enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If nginx is running, but cannot connect to its upstream server, e.g., to tomcat, then you'd be getting a 50x-style error, NOT a connection refused one.

> Browser reports site refused to connect. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED – Chethan S. Apr 21 at 15:34

This means that you cannot connect to nginx in the first place.  Are you sure it is running?

Best way to troubleshoot what's going on is to see what's running on your system, and on what ports and IP-addresses.  For example:

```
# lsof | fgrep -e LISTEN | fgrep -e tomcat -e nginx
nginx     25509              root   15u     IPv4           55825524      0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx     25529          www-data   15u     IPv4           55825524      0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx     25530          www-data   15u     IPv4           55825524      0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx     25531          www-data   15u     IPv4           55825524      0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx     25532          www-data   15u     IPv4           55825524      0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Make sure you see both tomcat and nginx in there.

Another approach would be to configure a firewall (e.g., iptables) to deny any attempts to connect to ports 8080 and 8443 from the outside, or only allow outside connections to ports 22 and 80/443 in the first place.

Comment: I get this output for the lsof command nginx     21140      root    6u     IPv4             815458       0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx     21142     nginx    6u     IPv4             815458       0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)
I suppose Tomcat is not listed since it probably shows as java and not Tomcat. Tomcat is actually running since I'm able to access the JIRA site without any issues.

Comment: @ChethanS., the information you provide about your situation is very inconsistent and quite contradictory -- how exactly are you able to access JIRA (from under tomcat) if tomcat is only listening on 127.0.0.1?  tomcat usually runs from under user `tomcat`, so, if you're not seeing it, chances are, it's not installed correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Actually, to make the site accessible until I find a solution, I removed address=127.0.0.1 from the server.xml file. In this case, where I have Jira installed, it takes care of Tomcat installation. Therefore, even the server.xml file is inside /opt/ folder hierarchy.

Comment: @ChethanS., so, what steps do you take to get the things running?  Are they all running within a single operating system instance?

Comment: yes, both Tomcat and Nginx are running in the same server.